# How to setup new ViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to set up a menu screen for my game. My game uses sprite kit and I was given `GameScene.swift` and `GameViewController.swift` by default (I used these for the game itself) I would now like to create a new view that will act as a menu screen. I have created two new files called `TitleScene.swift` and `TitleViewController.swift`. I am unsure what to put in the `viewDidLoad()` of the `TitleViewController.swift` file.

`GameViewController` (which was given to me by default, contains the following:

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

`unarchiveFromFile` uses an SKS file. However I have not included an SKS file for my new view as I plan to set up the view programatically so I thought I do not need one. Is this correct or do I in fact need an SKS file?

My question is how to I set up the new `TitleViewController`? I.e. what do I put in the `viewDidLoad()` method?

A tried and failed with the following:

```
let scene = TitleScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
let skView = self.view as SKView
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

This just causes a crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: You don't have to use an SKS file, for all of my Objective-C apps, I simply use a viewDidLoad that looks like the latter bit of code you provided. Is there anything else in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. There is nothing else in my `viewDidLoad` other than `super.viewDidLoad()` which is at the very first line of the `viewDidLoad` function.